# How to make All columns except one a datagridview column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview and it looks like this

[Datagridview Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHD2a.png)

My question is how can I make all columns as checkbox column except the month column?

Here is my code so far

```
  Dim con1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=192.168.2.87;userid=root;password=admin1950;database=inventory")
    Dim sql1 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select * from period_closure", con1)
    Dim ds1 As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim adapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter
    con1.Open()
    adapter1.SelectCommand = sql1
    adapter1.Fill(ds1, "MyTable")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
    con1.Close()
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns(0).Frozen = True
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        DataGridView1.Columns.Item(i).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
    Next i
```

I tried this code

```
For Each row in DatagridviewRow in Datagridview1.rows + 1
'+1 so the column month will not be affected
dim check as checkboxcolumn
row = checkboxcolumn
next
```

Its not working

TYSM for help

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: TY for commenting i been banned from asking because of this. I will update this again and hoping for an answer and an UpVote

Comment: @AndrewMortimer have you seen it?

Comment: Read this one, you should be able to find your answer there https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxt3k60s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: all i need is to make all columns as checkboxcolumn except in the Month column and pls be guided that all columns are in the mysql table

Comment: @AndrewMortimer a little bit of help is appreciated sir pls

Comment: @AndrewMortimer pls help

Comment: Which part of the documentation, which you read, didn't you understand?

Comment: Not to much sir i only read the Tristate but it looks like does not fit for me, All i want is populate a checkbox on all column except the `month` column I will update my post because i tried one

Comment: @AndrewMortimer have you seen it?

Comment: You can select columns by converting the to `bit` sql data type. Also you can add some `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` to your `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after the `DataSet` has been filled with columns but **before** binding the data to the `DataSet`

```
 dtSet.Tables(0).Columns(0).DataType = GetType(Boolean)
```

Comment: *Cannot change DataType of a column once it has data.*

Comment: I explicitly wrote **before** binding the data

Comment: Good job, I didn't see that :) But the user created the `DataTable`, the same time they load data.